# attempt to fix global 'SWEP' a nil value

Tags: function, lua, null

I am trying to create a weapon for a friend on Garry's Mod with Lua. I have made it through all other errors but I keep getting this error:

```
input:22: attempt to index global SWEP (a nil value)
```

I try to put a function before line 22 where it would say

`function SWEP.Base = "weapon_tttbase"` but then I would get an error saying `'(' expected near =`

```
if SERVER then
   AddCSLuaFile( "shared.lua" )
   SWEP.HoldType        = "normal"
end

if CLIENT then

   SWEP.PrintName           = "Cloak"
   SWEP.Slot                = 6

   SWEP.ViewModelFlip       = false

   SWEP.EquipMenuData = {
      type = "item_weapon",
      desc = "cloak_desc"
   };

   SWEP.Icon = "VGUI/ttt/icon_disguiser"
end

SWEP.Base = "weapon_tttbase"

SWEP.UseHands           = true
SWEP.ViewModelFlip      = false
SWEP.ViewModelFOV       = 70
SWEP.ViewModel          = "models/weapons/v_models/v_watch_spy.mdl"
SWEP.WorldModel         = "models/weapons/w_models/w_watch.mdl"

SWEP.ShowViewModel = true
SWEP.ShowWorldModel = true
SWEP.ViewModelBoneMods = {}

SWEP.Spawnable = true
SWEP.AdminSpawnable = true

SWEP.DrawCrosshair  = false
SWEP.Primary.ClipSize       = -1
SWEP.Primary.DefaultClip    = -1
SWEP.Primary.Automatic      = false
SWEP.Primary.Delay = 129.0
SWEP.Primary.Ammo   = "none"
SWEP.Primary.ClipMax    = -1
SWEP.AutoSpawnable  = false
SWEP.AmmoEnt        = "none"

SWEP.Kind = WEAPON_EQUIP1
SWEP.CanBuy = {ROLE_DETECTIVE} -- only detectives can buy
SWEP.LimitedStock = true -- only buyable once

SWEP.Primary.Sound = Sound( "hl2_sound_misc_000" )

-- Pull out faster than standard guns
SWEP.DeploySpeed = 2

SWEP.AllowDrop = false

SWEP.NoSights = true

SWEP.Initialize()
self.Weapon:SetNetworkFloat("energy",100)

function SWEP:Think()
if SERVER then
    if( self.Owner:KeyDown( IN_ATTACK ) ) then
    if self.Weapon:GetNetworkedFloat("energy") >0 then
        if self.Weapon:GetNetworkedFloat("energy") >0 then
      end
   end
end

self.Weapon:SetNetworkedFloat("energy",self.Weapon:GetNetworkedFloat("energy")-0.1)
        end
        if (self.Invis) then if self.Invis:IsValid() then return end
end
        self.Invis = ents.Create("ms_cloakent")
               self.Invis:SetPos(
self.Owner:GetPos()+Vector(0,0,50) )
             self.Invis:SetAngles( Vector(0,0,0) )
             self.Invis:SetParent( self.Owner )
             self.Invis:SetNetworkedEntity("parent",self.Owner)
             self.Invis:SetNetworkedBool("set",true)
        self.Invis:Spawn()
        self.Owner:DrawWorldModel(false)
        self.Owner:SetColor(255,255,255,0)
      end
        if (self.Invis) then
        if self.Invis:IsValid() then
            self.Invis:Remove()
            end
         end
        self.Owner:DrawWorldModel(true)
        self.Owner:SetColor(255,255,255,255)

        if (self.Invis) then
        if self.Invis:IsValid() then
            self.Invis:Remove()
            end
         end
        self.Owner:DrawWorldModel(true)
        self.Owner:SetColor(255,255,255,255)

        if self.Weapon:GetNetworkedFloat("energy") <100 then

self.Weapon:SetNetworkedFloat("energy",self.Weapon:GetNetworkedFloat("energy"))
end

function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
local effect = EffectData()
        effect:SetOrigin(self.Owner:GetPos())
    effect:SetScale(100)
util.Effect("super_explosion2", effect)
local effect = EffectData()
    effect:SetOrigin(self.Owner:GetPos())
    effect:SetScale(50)
util.Effect("super_explosion2", effect)
end

function SWEP:OnRemove()
        if (self.Invis) then
        if self.Invis:IsValid() then
            self.Invis:remove()
      end
   end
    return true
end

function SWEP (Holster)
        if (self.Invis) then
        if self.Invis:IsValid() then
            self.Invis:Remove()
      end
   end
    return true
end

if CLIENT then

function SWEP (DrawHUD)
    draw.RoundedBox( 10, ScrW()/2-20, ScrH/2-20, 40, 40,
Color(0,0,0,100) )
    draw.SimpleText(
tostring(math.Round(self.Weapon:GetNetworkedFloat("energy"))).."%",
"ChatFont", ScrW()/2, ScrH/2, Color(255,255,255,255), TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER,
TEXT_ALIGN_CENTER )
end

function SWEP (OnDrop)
   self:Remove()
end

function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
   self.Weapon:SetNextPrimaryFire( CurTime() + self.Primary.Delay )

   self:Cloak()
   end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Unless SWEP is a table that already exists when your code is loaded you are attempting to assign to SWEP.Base but SWEP does not exist (it is nil as the error indicates).

Also, you have multiple definitions of a SWEP function later. Only the last of which will actually exist when your code is finished running. That definition will also replace whatever table you had originally filled with all of your various SWEP.* assignments.

Comment: SWEP is defined, afaik. Edit: From the error, I pull this back. It SHOULD be defined by the game itself.

Comment: How are you running/using this script? Have you placed it in the correct file location for this sort of script?

Comment: `gamemodes/xxxx/entities/weapons/weaponfoldername/shared.lua` or `init.lua` or `cl_init.lua` as far as I know.